# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger ideal usage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

In my company we are already using Gerrit and we would want to integrate it with Jenkins for one project.
We have a dev server where the application would run and Jenkins will be installed, while Gerrit and the actual repo will be on a different one. Our goal is to sync the application on one server and run some scripts for building every time changes get merged on the dev branch.
The idea is not to perform builds on the Gerrit server, but on the server where our application runs. The Gerrit Jenkins plugin seems to be an ideal tool for such a task, as it would trigger builds on Gerrit events. However, I cannot come up with any ideal workflow or setup for our specific situation (basically copying files from A to B and running scripts on B), because I do not understand if, when using the Gerrit Plugin, the project is expected to be built on a specific branch or can be built anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins expects the code to be downloaded from the Gerrit server to the Jenkins server for running your build scripts.  Most users of the Gerrit Trigger Plugin use the Jenkins Git Plugin to accomplish this.  See the guide at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-UsagewiththeGitPlugin.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would be allowed to specify a destination for the code to be downloaded on the Jenkins server and, afterwards, run scripts on there. Am I wrong? I apologize if it might seem obvious but the reason I asked in the first place is because I have problems following that guide.

Comment: Each job gets a sandbox on the Jenkins node.  If you want to use a sub-directory of that sandbox, that might be an option.  But typically you don't specify the sandbox location and don't worry about where the code ends up.  If you need to move it somewhere else for publishing or similar, there are other post-build plugins for jenkins that can do so.

Answer (score 1):

The project will always be build in the job workspace. For example on Linux this would be in `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/job-name/workspace`. The workspace will be a clone of your repository and will be checked out to the branch that you wish to build.

So when you ask if you can specify a destination then I would say: No, this can not be done.

Why don't you use something like `rsync` to move your code to the final destination. This is what we use to deploy the latest documentation for our dev team.

1. Build software
2. Generate documentation
3. On success deploy docs: `rsync doc/html/ 192.168.0.1:/var/www/doc/project`